# If $x,y,z$ are three natural numbers are in A.P. and $x+y+z=21$ then the possible number of values of the ordered triplet $(x,y,z)$ is

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I have assumed $x=a-d,y=a$ and $z=a+d$ by which I get $a=7$  and numbers could be $1,7,13$ or $13,7,1$ or $7,7,7$,  but the total no of solutions set is $13$.

I am not getting it. Please help.

Comment: What about $(6,7,8)$, $(5,7,9)$, $(4,7,10)$, $(3,7,11)$, $(2,7,12)$?

Comment: gap between $x$ and $y$ and $y$ and $z$ does not have to be the same. $2, 7, 12$ or $3, 5, 13$ will also work.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: The problem statement says they are in an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z-y=y-x$. $x+z=2y$ and hence $3y=21$. So, $y=7$.

$x+z=2y=14$. So, $z=14-x$.

For any value of $x$, $x,7,14-x$ are in A.P.

If a natural number means a positive integer, them $x$ can take the values $1,2,3,\dots,13$.

Comment: I don't think $x>7$ is possible as it has to be ordered triplet.

Comment: @Vasya $(x,y,z)$ is an ordered triple does not mean that the three numbers are in ascending order.  The ordered triples $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ are not the same. But they are the same if they are regarded as unordered triples.